# Rails & Ajax: alternative to using [action_name].js.erb files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I've followed the excellent http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised to get some ajax functionality on my website.

The only problem is I reload an element in my sidebar meaning I need to make a [action_name].js.erb for every action of every controller on my website.

Is there a way to just place the following line of code in one file or location to make it work on the complete website?

Line of code I'm talking about in my [action_name[.js.erb:

```
$("#mol-form-dynamic").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("comments/mol_form")) %>");
```

application.js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#mol-form a").click(function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can make a `shared` dir in your `views` dir and place the same code in a file named say `sidebar_content.js.erb` and call this as from any action of any controller by putting below code at the end of your action.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render 'shared/sidebar_content.js.erb' }
end
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. The whole page stays blank.

Comment: Oh, my mistake ... in the above code please replace `shared/sidebar_content.js.erb` with just `shared/sidebar_content`

Comment: Tried that too but same problem

Comment: Can you please try the following : 1) Just put some test content by writing `$("#mol-form-dynamic").html("test content")` in your `js.erb` file and see if it getting replaced in the div ?

Comment: It shows up using the railscast way. Your way the page is still completely blank.